# Save only emails of today

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am creating a macro in Outlook 2010 that will save emails to a specified folder. The emails will be saved to a folder which is created by the macro. The problem in which I am accounting for is for when I receive emails over the weekend or off business hours. What I noticed is that when I receive emails over the weekend and reopen outlook on Monday, the macro runs fine and does what it needs to do, but the emails received over the weekend get put into the Monday folder. How can I bypass this problem. If I receive an email on Saturday, how can I have the macro so that it will create the folder for Saturday as well? This is the code I am currently working on.

```
Public Sub SaveMsgs(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
 Dim sPath As String
 Dim dtDate As Date
 Dim sName As String
 Dim enviro As String
 Dim sSender As String
 Dim strFolder As String
 Dim strNewFolder As String
 Dim save_to_folder As String

 enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))

 sName = Item.Subject
 ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "_"

 sSender = Item.Sender

 dtDate = Item.ReceivedTime
 sName = sSender & " - " & sName & ".msg"

 strNewFolder = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy")
 strFolder = "C:\IT Documents\" & strNewFolder & "\"

 If Len(Dir(strFolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
     MkDir (strFolder)
 End If

 save_to_folder = strFolder

 Item.SaveAs save_to_folder & sName, olMSG
End Sub


Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
 sChr As String _)

 sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
 sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
 sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
 sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
 sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
 sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
 sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
 sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you intended to use the `Item.ReceivedTime` to create your folder, but after you pull this value into `dtDate`, it never gets used.

Perhaps try the following instead:

```
strNewFolder = Format(dtDate, "mm-dd-yyyy")
                      ^^
```

Comment: This seems to have solved my issue. It's the little things that always get me. Thank you for your help and keen eye.

Comment: In the event in which I would potentially have a "duplicate" email, could I do something like this: 

    Do While True
      strMyPath = strFolder & sName
      If objFSO>FileExists(strMyPath) Then
         intCount = intCount + 1
         sName = Cop (" & intCount & ") 
      Else
         Exit Do
      End If
    Loop

Comment: I would maybe ask that as a separate question